# How to determine whether the current cursor position is inside a double or single quotes using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am trying to build a simple JavaScript text editor. I need to set a flag, say "quotesOn=true", when the user has started writing a string, e.g. "Hello world, how are your....". While writing the string, the variable "quotesOn" should remain "true", and it will be "false", only when the string has ended...i.e. using the last double-quote. I am looking for a solution in JavaScript or jQuery.

Case 1:

```
str =  "blah...blah...blah.......";
//     |                         |
//     |                         |________quotesOn=false
//     |______ quotesOn=true
```

Case 2:

```
str =  "blah...blah...\".....\"blah.........";
//     |               |                    |
//     |               |__ ignore this      |________quotesOn=false
//     |______ quotesOn=true
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u can use jQuery's [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) method and so if text editor has no content and when user focuses, set quotesOn=true and on focus out quotesOn=false..